# How to redirect screen log into syslog of cassandra snapshotter 1.0.0

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra

I'm using [cassandra snapshotter](https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter) to take backup of a cluster and upload into S3 but when I am executing the backup command:

```
 cassandra-snapshotter --aws-access-key-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx --aws-secret-access-key=xxxxxxxxxx --s3-bucket-name=xxxxx --s3-bucket-region=us-east-1 --s3-base-path=xxxx backup --hosts=xx.xx.xx.xx --keyspace xxxx  --user=xxxxx --password=xxxxx
```

and following logs are printing on screen.

```
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] sudo: cassandra-snapshotter-agent --incremental_backups put --   s3-bucket-name=xxxx --s3-bucket-region=us-east-1  --s3-base-path=xxxxxxx/20160531104350/xx.xx.xx.xx --manifest=/tmp/backupmanifest --bufsize=64 --concurrency=4 --aws-access-key-id=xxxxxx --aws-secret-access-key=xxxxx
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] out: lzop 1.03
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] out: LZO library 2.06
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] out: Copyright (C) 1996-2010 Markus Franz Xaver Johannes Oberhumer
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] out: 
 [xx.xx.xx.xx] out: cassandra_snapshotter.agent INFO    MSG: Initialized multipart upload for file /var/lib/cassandra/data/test/my_table-3035993026f911e695834dae91308d63/snapshots/20160531124729/test-my_table-ka-24-Index.db to 20160519/20160531124729/xx.xx.xx.xx//var/lib/cassandra/data/test/my_table-3035993026f911e695834dae91308d63/snapshots/20160531124729/test-my_table-ka-24-Index.db.lzo
 .......
 .......
```

I want to move screen log into dev/log/syslog. How to move the following log into the particular file with the help of small changing into codes. 
Is it possible to redirect the log?

In cassandra_snapshotter 1.0.0 , already code exists in logging_helper.py and How its work and where it is redirecting log.
can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`cassandra-snapshotter <args> | logger`

It looks like the lzop output is being generated from `compressed_pipe` in utils.py, and every call run with `fabric.api.sudo` will echo to stdout (see http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run). These aren't handled by the logging handler configured in `configure` in logging_helper.py.

To get stdout of the cassandra-snapshotter call sent to syslog, I would hope that you could just use `logger`, which, from the man page, is "a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module" (see http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger).